# Serialize nested object json jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, objectmapper

I am using Jackson json library to convert my POJOs to json:

```
    public class A {
        public String name;
        public B b;
    }

    public class B {
        public Object representation;
        public String bar;
    }
```

I want to serialize an instance of `A` into JSON. I am going to use the `ObjectMapper` class from **[Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)**:

```
objectMapperPropertiesBuilder.setSerializationFeature(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
objectMapperPropertiesBuilder.setAnnotationIntrospector(new CustomAnnotionIntrospector());
```

Here annotation introspector picks root element as all these are JAXB classes with annotations like `@XmlRootElement` and `@XmlType`:

Ex: If I set in `Object` representation:

```
    public class C {
        public BigInteger ste;
        public String cr;
    }
```

Using this code, my JSON would look like this:

```
rootA: {
  "name": "MyExample",
  "b": {
    "rep": {
      "ste": 7,
      "cr": "C1"
    },
    "bar": "something"
  }
}
```

But I want the root element appended to my nested `Object` too. Object can be any custom POJO.

So in this case, I would want root element of class `C` appended in my JSON conversion. So:

```
rootA: {
  "name": "MyExample",
  "b": {
    "rep": {
      "rootC": {
        "ste": 7,
        "cr": "C1"
      }
    },
    "bar": "something"
  }
}
```

How can I add the root element of a nested object in JSON conversion ? All the `objectMapper` properties I specified will be applicable to `class A`. Do I have to write a custom serializer to apply some properties to nested object ?

Comment: Please be aware that the JSON you provided in your question are not valid. You can validate them [here](http://jsonlint.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom serializer for that. However, the easiest way to achieve what you want is using a `Map` to wrap the `C` instance:

```java
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("rootC", c);
```

Your classes would be like:

```java
@JsonRootName(value = "rootA")
public class A {
    public String name;
    public B b;
}
```

```java
public class B {
    @JsonProperty("rep")
    public Object representation;
    public String bar;
}
```

```java
public class C {
    public BigInteger ste;
    public String cr;
}
```

The code to create the JSON would be:

```java
A a = new A();
a.name = "MyExample";

B b = new B();
b.bar = "something";

C c = new C();
c.cr = "C1";
c.ste = new BigInteger("7");

a.b = b;

Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("rootC", c);
b.representation = map;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(a);
```

And the generated JSON would be:

```json
{
  "rootA" : {
    "name" : "MyExample",
    "b" : {
      "rep" : {
        "rootC" : {
          "ste" : 7,
          "cr" : "C1"
        }
      },
      "bar" : "something"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works but setting the input is not in my hand. I get an object filled and I have to serialize it, so I am not the one setting `Map` (client does that). So I should go for Custom serializer ?

Comment: And if I go for Custom serializer, I just want the `representation` part to be serialized using a customized way and rest all properties are serialized using the `ObjectMapper` properties I set in my Root class. How can that be achieved ??

Comment: Also, my POJOs too are not editable for annotations. Will have to use `ObjectMapper`